# How to overload method taking predicate vs value in c++

Tags: c++, stl

Please feel free to rephrase the title if it is not appropriate. I am trying to come up with a wrapper on top of find and find_if algorithms in STL. This is what I have for now.

```
template<typename Type, size_t SIZE>
int IndexOf(const Type(&arr)[SIZE], const Type& val)
{
    return IndexOf( arr, arr + SIZE, val);
}

template<typename Iter, typename Type>
int IndexOf(Iter first, Iter last, const Type& val)
{
    auto index = find(first, last, val);

    if ( index != last)
    {
        return distance(first, index);
    }
    return -1;
}


template<typename Type, size_t SIZE, typename Pred>
int IndexOf(const Type(&arr)[SIZE], Pred pred)
{
    return IndexOf(arr, arr + SIZE, pred);
}


template<typename Iter, typename Pred>
int IndexOf(Iter first, Iter last, Pred pred)
{
    auto index = find_if(first, last, pred);

    if ( index != last)
    {
        return distance(first, index);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The below usage fails to compile saying ambiguous overload.

```
vector<string> names;
names.push_back("Jagan");
names.push_back("Gagan");
names.push_back("Magan");
names.push_back("Pagan");
names.push_back("Vagan");

std::cout << "Index of (Gagan)" << IndexOf(begin(names), end(names), 
                                          [](const string& name)
                                          {
                                        return name == "Gagan";
                                          });
```

The above example usage is just for brevity.

Comment: Try `const typename Iter::value_type & val` in the second overload.

Comment: @Kerreck SB, -1 was a mistake. Did not test it full.Was looking at the compilation problem than the logic.

Comment: Consider using `std::size_t` for your indices.

Comment: @pmr, Sure. Just trying to get around the actual problem. Now the solution that evolved that auto as return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as the stdlib does: Don't overload. The stdlib for example provides two functions that let you search for something in a range.

One is named `find` ( like "find that value!"), and the other is named `find_if` (like "found if the predicate returns true!").

---

Another option might be to employ some SFINAE trickery (using C++11 and expression SFINAE):

```
template<class T>
T create();

template<class InIt, class T>
auto find(InIt first, InIt last, T const& value)
    -> decltype((*first == value), create<InIt>())
{
  // ...
}
```

This function will be removed from the overload set, if `*first == value` is not a valid expression (you normally don't store predicates in a container and search with the same predicate in it).

The `, create<InIt>()` in `decltype` is to give it a return type of `InIt`. `create` is undefined, because it will only ever used in unevaluated contexts, and as such doesn't need a definition (which makes life easier, we don't have to guess how we could actually construct such an object. We simply take the type `InIt`). If I had used `first` instead of `create<InIt>()`, the return type would've been `InIt&`, which would be slightly surprising and not good, since you're return a reference to a local variable

```
template<class Init, class Pred>
auto find(InIt first, InIt last, Pred pred)
    -> decltype((pred(*first)?0:0), create<InIt>())
{
  // ...
}
```

This function will be removed from the overload set, if `pred(*first)` is not a valid expression, i.e. `pred` doesn't take the `value_type` of `InIt` as a parameter. It will furthermore be removed, if the return type of `pred`'s `operator()` isn't explicitly convertible to `bool`, tested through the use `?:`, the ternary logical operator. Again, the `, create<InIt>()` is used to give the function the `InIt` return type.

Here's a [small live example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/zn7as) for your specific case. Note that I did not use `create<int>()` here, because literal `0` is already of type `int`.

Comment: Now it returns `InIt&`. May or may not be important.

Comment: @Jagannath: Please not that this answer still contains some issues I'm in the process of resolving.

Comment: I prefer the overloaded version.

Comment: @Jagannath: There, all fixed up. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to comment. :)

Comment: @Xeo, :-) Thanks. That was tricky. Failed to compile in VS11 Dev. preview ( I know it's a dev. preview ). But compiled on g++ and clang.

Comment: The versions taking array as arguments are left without any modification and they worked since they are implemted in terms of the overloaded versions.

Comment: @Jagannath: I think VS11 fails, because it doesn't correctly implement expression SFINAE. You can try to work around that with the usual `enable_if` construct and `is_constructible` amongst others from `<type_traits>`. I'll see if I can get a version of that up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat cheeky way to disambiguate the two overloads: If the iterator's value type can be constructed from the argument, we pick `find`, otherwise we treat the argument as a predicate:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Iter>
int IndexOf(Iter first, Iter last, typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type const & val)
{
    auto index = std::find(first, last, val);
    return index != last ? std::distance(first, index) : -1;
}

template<typename Iter, typename Pred>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_constructible<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type, Pred>::value, int>::type
IndexOf(Iter first, Iter last, Pred pred)
{
    auto index = std::find_if(first, last, pred);
    return index != last ? distance(first, index) : -1;
}
```